# Query not running. There is # in mysql password

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a mysqldump command from mac terminal. There is # in the password. Getting `-bash: !3: event not found` error in the terminal.

The command: `mysql -uUNAME -pPASSWORD#PASS -e "SELECT * from TABLE_NAME" DB_NAME | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' > /Users/Desktop/name.csv`

Need help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the password in quotes `-p"PASSWORD#PASS"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape special chars with backslash like

**The command:**

```
mysql -uUNAME -pPASSWORD\#PASS -e "SELECT * from TABLE_NAME" DB_NAME | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' > /Users/Desktop/name.csv
```

Comment: do you have other special chars in the Password like ! $ ;

Comment: Yup. Will try adding '\' for them too. Have $,*,! as well.